# MVC : Routing route value acting strange?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, view, controller, routes

I have a **viewmodel** which looks like

```
 public class BusinessUnitDetail
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public LicensesDetails LicensesDetails { get; set; }
        public RepresentativeDetails RepresentativeDetails { get; set; }
    }
 public class LicensesDetails
    {

        public string BusinessUnitName { get; set; }
        public List<LicensesVM> Licenses { get; set; }
    }
public class RepresentativeDetails
    {

        public string BusinessUnitName { get; set; }
        public List<RepresentativeVM> Representatives { get; set; } 
    }
```

Currently my view contains two tables which shows **List of Representative** and **List of Licenses**.
Here is the **view**, quite long but anyways

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "BusinessUnitDetails";
    Layout = "~/Views/shared/_BootstrapLayout.basic.cshtml";
    int snor = 1;
    int snol = 1;
}

<fieldset>
    <legend>@Model.Name <small>Representatives</small></legend>
</fieldset>
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
    <caption></caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>S.No</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    @foreach (var entry in Model.RepresentativeDetails.Representatives)
    {

        <tr>
            @*@Html.HiddenFor(m=>entry.BusinessUnitId)*@
            <td>@(snor++)</td>

            <td>@entry.UserName</td>
            <td>
                <div class="btn-group" >
                    <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        Action<span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Details", "RepresentativeDetails",routeValues:new{entry.BusinessUnitId})</li>

                    </ul>
                </div>    
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>

<fieldset>
    <legend>@Model.Name <small>Licenses</small></legend>
</fieldset>
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
    <caption></caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>S.No</th>
            <th>Kind</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    @foreach (var entry in Model.LicensesDetails.Licenses)
    {

        <tr>
           @* @Html.HiddenFor(m=>entry.BusinessUnitId)*@
            <td>@(snol++)</td>

            <td>@entry.LicenseName</td>
            <td>
                <div class="btn-group" >
                    <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        Action<span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Details", "LicenseDetails",routeValues:new{entry.BusinessUnitId})</li>

                    </ul>
                </div>    
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

When i click the **Details** action of some row in **License table**, I expected it to redirect me to `LicenseDetails` action method as stated in `Html.ActionLink`, but it doesn't.
The route when i click the details action is

```
Customer/businessunit/LicenseDetails?BusinessUnitId=25c70a1d-0ed5-406f-8cae-1c6c1bf7d0da
```

I don't know how the **LicenseDetails?BusinessUnitId=** part is being generated, and why the action doesn't forward to the LicenseDetails method in controller.
What can I do so that, when i click the details action in second table, I get forwarded to proper controller action which proper Guid id
Any idea?

**Edit 1: License Detail Action Methode**

```
public ActionResult LicenseDetails(Guid licenseId)
        {
            var licenseDetails = _businessUnitRepository.GetLicenseDetail(licenseId);
            return View(licenseDetails);
        }
```

Comment: What is BusinessUnitId? I don't see a property for it.

Comment: Its a Guid, the guid value you can see in route is the value it holds

Comment: Can you show us the `LicenseDetails` Action Method signature?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this syntax:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "LicenseDetails", new { licenseId = entry.BusinessUnitId })
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ActionLink seems fit to some routes. Type it more strongly with controllername:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "LicenseDetails", "Home", new { licenseId = entry.BusinessUnitId }, null)
```